# What is the simplest design to replicate Oerstead's experiment at home?

Tags: power-supply

I want to demonstrate what Oerstead did several centuries ago. He demonstrated that there is magnetic field near a current carrying wire.

I have a compass that is sensitive to earth magnetic field of about 25-65 micro tesla. I attempted to replicate the experiment with a wire and an  accumulator of 12 volt, 7 Ah. Even though I short circuited the accumulator for about several milliseconds, the produced current is not enough to generate magnetic field that can deflect the compass needle.

$$
B=\frac{\mu_0 i}{2 \pi r}
$$

For `r=0.05` m I need about 16.25 ampere to produce 65 micro tesla.

## Question

What is the simplest design to create a DC power supply that can produce about 16.25 ampere or more?

Comment: You should not short out such a battery, it is quite dangerous.   And do not use any sort of rechargeable battery either.  Just one of the old carbon-zinc flashlight cells in C or D size might have been appropriate if you can find one, and use a few meters of thin diameter wire.  But do to this right you really need a current limited power supply.

Comment: You wrote "For r=0.05 cm". It's For r=0.05m (i.e. 5cm)

Comment: Why 5cm? 2.5 cm would halve the current. 1cm would be less than 3A.

Comment: Much easier to use more than one wire, carrying the same current. That is, a loop of multiple turns carrying the same current. That means you need less current.

Comment: I conducted an experiment where I was able to detect the magnetic field from the current of a 1.5 volt battery passing through a 5 foot loop of wire. I was able to detect the field over five away. If you’re really interested I would repost it to YouTube for you.

Comment: Sorry, I left the units off my first comment, too late to edit. I was able to detect it five feet away.

Comment: Here it is: https://youtu.be/53RVKc5R2bs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the simplest design to replicate Oerstead's experiment at home?
>
> I want to demonstrate what Oerstead did several centuries ago. He demonstrated that there is magnetic field near a current carrying wire.

That can be done very simply and easily. All you need is any simple magnetic compass, a piece of wire and a battery. It is best to use a single alkaline or zinc-carbon C-cell or D-cell. They produce only 1.5 volts, thus not a very high current, and are not susceptible to rapid overheating when shorted.

Simply align the wire with the compass as shown below. Connect the ends of the wire to the battery. The compass will deflect as shown. If you pinch the wire to the battery with your fingers the heat at the connection points could be a little uncomfortable, but not harmful if you don't do it for long.

[image]

> What is the simplest design to create a DC power supply that can produce about 16.25 ampere or more?

I believe the illustrated method produced something close to 16 amps. It produced more than 10 amps in my shorted meter leads. However the battery may not last long enough. Oersted did more than demonstrate that there is a magnetic field near a current-carrying wire. He also demonstrated that the field has a circular shape. If you want a power supply to demonstrate that continuously, I would recommend finding a transformer from which you can remove the secondary winding and replace it with a winding with fewer turns of larger wire so the secondary produces only 2 or 3 volts. Connect it to a suitable rectifier. Connect wire or wire plus some resistance that will result in whatever current the transformer is rated for.